# Can 2D and 3D plots be combined so that the 2D plot is the bottom surface of the 3D plot boundary?

Tags: graphics, plotting, graphics3d

I have a `ListlinePlot` function, that I would like to combine with both a `Graphics3D` plot and a `ListPointPlot3D` plot, in such a way that the `ListLinePlot` is the bottom of the 3D boundary cube for the 3D plots. Can this be done in Mathematica 8.0.4?

Obviously the code below fails to combine the plots in `Show`, but is there another way to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
    Needs["TetGenLink`"]
twodPts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
threedPts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[threedPts];

twoDptsPlot = ListLinePlot[twodPts, ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
threeDPtsPlot = ListPointPlot3D[threedPts, ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
surfacePlot = 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.3], 
    GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]], ImageSize -> {200, 200}}];

{twoDptsPlot, 
 Show[threeDPtsPlot, surfacePlot, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> False]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've edited your code a bit, and included some figure, please feel free to roll back if you don't agree with the change in the `Show` line.

Comment: I seem to remember we have had the same type of question before, perhaps on SO/mathematica. Can't find it at the moment. One easy approach would be to `Texture` a plane with the 2D plot.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486907/display-multiple-2d-plots-in-3d-using-graphics-in-mathematica) might help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following is probably what you want.

```
Make3d[plot_, height_, opacity_] := 
  Module[{newplot},
    newplot = First@Graphics[plot]; 
    newplot = N@newplot /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} :> {x, y, height};
    newplot /. GraphicsComplex[xx__] :> {Opacity[opacity], GraphicsComplex[xx]}
  ]

Show[{Graphics3D[Make3d[twoDptsPlot, -1, .75]], threeDPtsPlot,surfacePlot}, Axes -> True]
```

which gives
[image]

This function can takes any 2D plot and place it on a 3D box with a specified height. I got this trick in the web few years back but now cant remember the reference. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I saw the method in this a while ago.
http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2009/02/howto-display-2d-plot-in-3d.html

Comment: @Ajasja You are right this is the link I was looking for..

Comment: @PlatoManiac Make3d[plot_, height_, opacity_] does not respect the colour of plot_ when this made by Graphics, for example: s = Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> Red] 

Show[{Graphics3D[Make3d[s, 0, 100.8]]}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False] what can I do to stick to the original colour?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard♦ any idea on my comment just above ?

Comment: @Mencia Sjoerd's `Texture` method is probably easiest if you want a complete image of the 2D plot with all options considered.  (You can rasterize at a higher resolution of the texture quality is not as good as you would like.)  Otherwise I would suggest manually adding specific handling for `BaseStyle` and anything else you want, perhaps `Prolog` and `Epilog`, `Background`, etc.  If you have trouble extracting and integrating these option values let me know.

Answer (score 13):

You explicitly ask for the `ListLinePlot` to be placed in the `Graphics3D`, not just the lines contained in the plot. Since none of the answers so far do that here is my version.

```
surfacePlot = 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[twoDptsPlot], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
     {Opacity[0.3], GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]}}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"]

Show[surfacePlot, threeDPtsPlot, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks like a cool approach @Sjoerd C. de Vries, thanks for the great code!

Comment: Might want to use `Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[twoDptsPlot, Background -> None]]]` if you need the texture to have transparency.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries @Mr.Wizard♦ I am trying to use this method. But I would like to combine the ListLinePlot with a ListPlot3D. I am trying this: surfacePlot = Graphics3D[{
   EdgeForm[],
   {Texture[twoDptsPlot], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}
   , ListPlot3D[{{1, 4, 2}, {6, 3, 9}, {1, 9, 4}}]},
  ImageSize -> 400,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"] but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

This is an approach that uses the graphics primitive `Line`.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
twodPts = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10}], 
    Table[-1, {10}]}];
threedPts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[threedPts];
twoDptsPlot = Graphics3D[Line[twodPts], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
threeDPtsPlot = ListPointPlot3D[threedPts, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}];
surfacePlot = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.3], GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]],
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}}];
Show[threeDPtsPlot, surfacePlot, twoDptsPlot, ImageSize -> {200, 200},
    BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Very Cool!  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

Just in case using a single `Graphics3D` may be of interest:

```
Graphics3D[{
  PointSize[.01], Red, Point /@ threedPts, 
  Blue, Thickness[.003], Line@(Insert[#, -1, -1] & /@ twodPts), 
  GraphicsComplex[pts, {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.4]}], Polygon[surface]}], 
  ImageSize -> {200, 200}
}]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Some amazing answers here!  Thanks so much!