# More on combining 2d and 3d plots

Tags: plotting

This is a spin off/follow up to [Can 2D and 3D plots be combined so that the 2D plot is the bottom surface of the 3D plot boundary?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3665/1629) ...

Following Sjoerd's method, I did this:

```
image = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]; 
Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[image], 
Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
Lighting -> "Neutral", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1}], Boxed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Two questions:

(1) When I click on the cell bracket and save as... PDF, the resulting graphic is either empty or only contains a snippet of the intended graphic.

(2) I would like to have Mathematica draw the solid which has the region bounded by the parabola and the x axis as its base, but with cross-sections (perpendicular to the base) to be squares. I am not sure how to go about this using Graphics3D.

Any ideas?

Edit: RegionPlot3D indeed allows me to answer (2) very quickly:

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
p2 = RegionPlot3D[-Sqrt[y] <= x <= Sqrt[y] && 
 0 <= z <= 2 Sqrt[y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
p3 = Show[
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[p1], 
 Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], Boxed -> True]
```

Now my only issue is how to lay the solid in p2 over the image in p3? I tried

```
Show[p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

and other variations, to no avail.

Edit #2: Should have had RegionPlot z range as {z,0,4}. Fixed now. Also, the slices can be visualized via

```
slices = Table[RegionPlot3D[-Sqrt[y] <= x <= Sqrt[y] && 0 <= z <= 2 Sqrt[y] && 
 j - .5 <= y <= j, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], {j, .5, 4, .5}];
Show[Table[slices[[j]], {j, 1, 8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking what `but with cross-sections (perpendicular to the base) to be squares.` means. Could you upload a hand drawing?

Comment: I can reproduce your PDF problems. Save to EPS doesn't work either, but SVG (also a vector format) works fine. Perhaps that might be a solution.

Comment: You've looked at `RegionPlot3D[]` for your second question?

Comment: @belisarius: Compile this `p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
p2 = Table[
   Plot[j/2, {x, -Sqrt[j/2], Sqrt[j/2]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], {j, 1, 8}];
p3 = Show[p1, p2];
Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[p3], 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1}], Boxed -> True]` the blue lines would form the bottom edge of a square.

Comment: Ok. If don't post a (hand)drawing of your desired result, I'll leave this one for others

Comment: @belisarius: see the edit above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
p2 = RegionPlot3D[-Sqrt[y] <= x <= Sqrt[y] && 
    0 <= z <= 2 Sqrt[y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
p3 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[p1], 
    Polygon[{{-2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -1}, {2, 4, -1}, {-2, 4, -1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];

Graphics3D[{p2[[1]], p3[[1]]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image: solid]

Here I modified your `p3` to make the polygon bigger so its boundaries are described by `{{-2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -1}, {2, 4, -1}, {-2, 4, -1}}`. The texture on the polygon is of course not perfectly aligned with the 3D `RegionPlot` because the 2D plot contains additional margins for the axes and labels. But I'm using what you provided in the question.

Finally, the main point is that in order to combine the two `Graphics3D` objects `p2` and `p3`, I used the fact that the actual 3D graphics *objects* are always stored as the first element of the `Graphics3D`, so one can extract them by doing `p2[[1]]` and `p3[[1]]`. The results can then be re-packaged into a *new* `Graphics3D` as I do on the last line, adding the lighting and frame options that you chose for `p3` in your example.

**Note**

If you do this kind of combination more frequently, you may also want to look  into the closely related answer I posted under [“Covering up” text in Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245) where I define a function `label3D` which can be used to place arbitrary 2D objects into a 3D scene, including transparency effects.

Comment: Hmmm... I updated to 8.0.4 and neither this one or the label3D "Surprise!" example shows up for me.

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce the result above? For me, the bottom graphic appears if and only if Opacity[1]. I'll post the code in the next comment due to space limitations.

Comment: `p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]; Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[p1], 
    Polygon[{{-2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -1}, {2, 4, -1}, {-2, 4, -1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
    Opacity[w]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False],
  RegionPlot3D[-Sqrt[y] <= x <= Sqrt[y] && 
    0 <= z <= 2 Sqrt[y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 10, PlotStyle -> Opacity[w], 
   Boxed -> False], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], {w, 0, 1, .1}]`