# Placing a ContourPlot under a Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to combine a 3-dimensional graph of a function with its 2-dimensional contour-plot underneath it in a professional way.  But I have no idea how to start.

I have a three of these I would like to make, so I don't need a fully automated function that does this.  A giant block of code would be just fine.

The two plots I would like to have combined are:

```
potential1 = 
  Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4, 
    {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10,
    MeshStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue}, Lighting -> "Neutral",
    MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.4], Blue}, {Opacity[.2], Blue}}, Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False]
```

and

```
contourPotentialPlot1 = 
  ContourPlot[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4, 
   {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7},
   Contours -> 10, ContourStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue}}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 30]
```

These two plots look like:

[image: The 3-D plot]
[image: The contour plot]

I would also love it if I could get 'grids' on the sides of the box like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GammaAbsSmallPlot.png

---

**Update**
The new plotting routine `SliceContourPlot3D` was introduced in version 10.2.  If this function can be used to achieve the task above, how can it be done?

Comment: For the grids look up `FaceGrids` in the docs.

Comment: Looks like you want something like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7772/5 (see Jens' answer)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Strategy is simple texture map 2D plot on a rectangle under your 3D surface. I took a liberty with some styling that I like - you can always come back to yours.

```
contourPotentialPlot1 = ContourPlot[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 
   0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, Contours -> 15, Axes -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"];

potential1 = Plot3D[-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 
    0.125 s^4, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1.4*10^8, 2*10^7}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], Orange}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

level = -1.2 10^8; gr = Graphics3D[{Texture[contourPotentialPlot1], EdgeForm[], 
Polygon[{{-400, -300, level}, {400, -300, level}, {400, 300, level}, {-400, 300, level}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[potential1, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]

You can see I used `PlotRangePadding -> 0` option in `ContourPlot`. It is to remove white space around the graphics to make texture mapping more precise. If you need utmost precision you can take another path. Extract graphics primitives from `ContourPlot` and make them 3D graphics primitives. If you need to color the bare contours - you could replace `Line` by `Polygon` and do some tricks with `FaceForm` based on a contour location.

```
level = -1.2 10^8;
pts = Append[#, level] & /@ contourPotentialPlot1[[1, 1]];
cts = Cases[contourPotentialPlot1, Line[l_], Infinity];
cts3D = Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, {Opacity[.5], cts}]];

Show[potential1, cts3D, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, 
 FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Back, Left}]
```

[image]

Comment: in addition to OP's question, how can I add a legend for the contourplot without distorting the projection from below? I tried adding PlotLegends but it distorted the contourplot

Comment: How can I use the second form in v12+? The internal representation of plots seems to have changed.

Answer (score 50):

A simpler version but not as nice as Vitally's is this:

```
potential1 /. 
 Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> 
  Graphics3D[{gr, Scale[gr, {1, 1, 1/100}, {0, 0, -2 10^8}]}, 
   PlotRange -> All, opts]
```

[image]

This can also be "projected" onto the other sides.

```
potential1 /. 
 Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> 
  Graphics3D[{gr, Scale[gr, {1, 1, 1/100}, {0, 0, -2 10^8}], 
    Scale[gr, {1/100, 1, 1}, {-400, 0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> All, opts]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Neat trick ;) For good graphics quality keep PlotPoints option high in this case for original surface - like around 50 or more.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov True, I have corrected that now. Looks nicer.

Comment: +1 I used that trick in [this question about drop shadows](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1030/245), too. If you want to project along a direction that's not parallel to the axes, there's just the additional complication that the scales along different axes may be different in the output of `Plot3D` - that's certainly the case in this potential plot. Anyway, it doesn't make a difference for a vertical projection as you did here.

Comment: @Jens Didn't know about your answer. Thanks for the link. In Mathematica V2 (if memory serves right) I used a function called `ShadowPlot3D` that did this type of pseudo projection.

Comment: I want to mark this answer is correct as well.  How can I do that?

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks, but you can't. Only one answer can get the green tick. The other answers still get their point according to peer review. I personally think Vitally's answer deserves the tick. That's what I would have done too.

Comment: Sometimes there's more than one correct answer...

Answer (score 37):

Here's one using `SliceContourPlot3D` (introduced in 10.2) and Vitaliy's stylings.

```
f = -3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4;

min = -1.4*10^8;
max = 2*10^7;

potential1 = Plot3D[f, {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {min, max}, ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], Orange}}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image]

```
slice = SliceContourPlot3D[f, z == min, 
  {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, {z, min - 1, min + 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {min, max}, Contours -> 15, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"
]
```

[image]

```
Show[potential1, slice, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]

Comment: You should mention that `SliceContourPlot3D` is a new feature

Comment: @eldo Thanks, done!

Comment: It's too bad `"BackPlanes"` does not allow for just depicting two or one of them.

Comment: It is good to see how these sorts of things get easier to do as the language progresses.

Answer (score 13):

So late to the party but here is my take:

```
f[h_, s_] := -3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 0.125 s^4; 
min = -1.4*10^8; max = 2*10^7;

contour = 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -400, 400}, {y, -300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {min, max}, Axes -> False, Contours -> 15, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
potential1 = 
 Plot3D[f[h, s], {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {min, max}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], Orange}}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {min, 2}}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, both combined:

```
Show[potential1, 
Graphics3D[contour[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, min}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]