# How to flip texture?

Tags: textures

I discovered [this excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14875/13074) which contains a so beautiful plot.

I just copied the whole code and tried to reproduce the result but the contour plot used as texture looks like flipped, that is, when I see the plot from above the result is

[image]

and if I see it from below the result is

[image]

How to fix this? I mean, how to put the white color visible from the top?

I'm using *Mathematica* 9.

Comment: Add `FaceForm[Opacity[1], Opacity[.8]]` before `Texture[..]` in the definition of `gr`.

Comment: @kguler, it does not work. Your code just make the bottom white color transparent so that I can see from bottom to top; and the top gray color becomes the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you have an object in a three-dimensional scene that needs to be displayed independently of the lighting conditions, it's a good idea to give that object a [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html). From the docs:

> `Glow` is a color component independent of simulated illumination.

This is what I use in the definition of `gr` (last line before `Show` in the answer linked in the question):

```
gr = Graphics3D[{Glow[White], Texture[contourPotentialPlot1], 
    EdgeForm[], 
    Polygon[{{-400, -300, level}, {400, -300, level}, {400, 300, 
       level}, {-400, 300, level}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];
```

Everything else can stay the same, and you now have the two-dimensional plot appearing bright in all directions.

Comment: Ow, thanks! It works perfectly now. Do you know why I got a different result from you or maybe there is a typo on the linked code so that plots does not correspond to that code?

Comment: It's true, I get the darker appearance in the bottom view, not the top view, when no `Glow` is added. I'm using *Mathematica* version 8, what are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 9 on Linux.

Comment: @Sigur That's a bit mysterious, but if the standard steps of restarting the Kernel and copying verbatim from the answer don't help, then it must be a version-dependent problem. Anyway, I hope the `Glow` method will help avoid this issue.

Comment: Well, I restarted the software but no progress. Your suggestion to use `Glow` works nice and I also used the `Opacity` as suggested by kguler so now I can see from bottom to top. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it could (though very unlikely) be that you set some obsolete options like `LightSources` in some init.m file and they could still be affecting the assumed position of the `Lighting`. Not sure about that, but you could experiment by trying some of the more explicitly specified settings from the documentation for `Lighting` and see if the results look like the pictures in the examples...

Comment: I never changed anything. I just installed it and started to copy some examples from here. I have no idea how to edit `init.m`.

Comment: @Jens Have V9 and Linux too and it is not lighted from upside down. My first guess was that he messed with the Lighting options too. If not, the issue is really mysterious.