# How to combine VectorPlot and Plot3D

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a problem with VectorPlot and Plot3D, and I have a code for both but I dont know how to plot the same figure.
Here is the code for Plot3D:

```
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
op = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 2;
Subscript[Γ, D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};
Φ = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
Plot3D[{-Subscript[τ, yz] - Subscript[τ, xz]}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, PlotStyle -> None, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(zy\)]\)(x,y)"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"]]
```

And the code for VectorPlot:

```
Subscript[τ, yz] = -\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(Φ[x, y]\)\);
Subscript[τ, xz] = \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(y\)]\(Φ[x, y]\)\);
VectorPlot[{Subscript[τ, xz],  Subscript[τ, yz]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

I found this link but I dont understand how can use for my code:
http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/26013
[image]

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I have changed so solution and vector plot match:

Subscript[τ, yz] = -D[Φ[x, y], x]; 
Subscript[τ, xz] = D[Φ[x, y], y]; 

vp = VectorPlot[{Subscript[τ, xz], Subscript[τ, yz]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]; 
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]; 
op = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 2; 

Subscript[Γ, D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}; 

Φ =  NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]}, u,  Element[{x, y}, Ω]]; 

p = Plot3D[Φ[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Ω], PlotStyle -> None
  , PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> True,  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(zy\)]\)(x,y)"}, 
       LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier New"]
];

ar = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], 
    Blue, (Arrow[PadRight[#1, {Length[#1], 2, 3}, 0]] & )[
           Cases[vp, Arrow[l_] :> l, -1]]}]; 

Show[p, ar]
```

[image: sd]

This is just application from the community code. The arrows from the `VectorPlot` are extracted using `Cases`. They are then padded with z- coordinate relevant for your plot and with what style/format desired.

Comment: Why did you prefer recasting `vp` as `ar` instead of using `Texture[vp]`?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I adapted the code from the link in OP question...which I thought was his desired approach. Texture can produce desired effect but depending on situation requires dealing with axis offsets and other distortions...cannibalising 2D graphics object and repotting as 3D avoids this and makes easier to alter elements.