# plotting 3d and contour

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can i plot such a graph like this?

I mean placing the 3d plot and the contour in the same figure
[image]

Comment: Have a look here [Plotting a function with insight to a special plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103873/plotting-a-function-with-insight-to-a-special-plot/103880#103880) and here [Placing a ContourPlot under a Plot3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d?lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Louis pointed in the comment get this done just by combining `Plot3D` and `SliceContourPlot3D` if you are having post 10.2 MMA.

```
fun[x_, y_] := Sin[x + y] Cos[x - y];
Show[Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], Specularity[White, 50]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FaceGrids -> None], 
 SliceContourPlot3D[fun[x, y], 
  z == -1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

You can control the vertical position by setting suitable value for `z`. Note that I have used `z=-1` in `SliceContourPlot3D`.

In case you want to avoid `SliceContourPlot3D` you can resort to the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/can-2d-and-3d-plots-be-combined-so-that-the-2d-plot-is-the-bottom-surface-of-the/3667#3667).