# Manipulate with Contours and 3D plots

Tags: plotting, manipulate

First question in this community (and rather new to the Mathematica world): thanks in advance for your help and sorry if the solution to the question is completely trivial!

I would like to have contours with 3D plots in the spirit of the question [plotting 3d and contour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104703/plotting-3d-and-contour) (along with selected answer), with the addition of manipulate on a given parameter. Thus, for example, in line with the aforementioned previous question, how should I modify this piece of code to get the plot changing with variations wrt to $a$:

```
fun[x_, y_] := x + a y;
Show[Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], Specularity[White, 50]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FaceGrids -> None], 
 SliceContourPlot3D[fun[x, y], 
  z == -1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]]
```

I did try to put `Manipulate` in between `Show` and `Plot3D` (with related brackets added), but it didn't work out.

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Module[{fun},
  fun[x_, y_] = x + a y;
  Show[Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], Specularity[White, 50]], 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    FaceGrids -> None], 
   SliceContourPlot3D[fun[x, y], 
    z == -1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]]], {a, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated! If you want to write it down as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the `fun[x_,y_]=x+a*y` by `Module` work.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{fun}, fun[x_, y_] = x + a y; 
  Show[Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], Specularity[White, 50]], 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    FaceGrids -> None], 
   SliceContourPlot3D[fun[x, y], 
    z == -1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]]], {a, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: I just wrote a follow up to this question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280179/multiple-plots-with-same-colors-under-one-manipulate