# Multiple Plots (with same colors) under one Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a follow up to my previous question regarding manipulate with contours and 3D plots
[Manipulate with Contours and 3D plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280175/manipulate-with-contours-and-3d-plots)

How can I achieve three (!) plots under the same `Manipulate`?
The three plots should be:
– the aforementioned answer,
– a 3D plot alone (the standard one),
– a contour plot (the standard one again).

I was thinking about using `Column` (as in this link https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1313104), but I am afraid I am far away from the technical skills needed.

As a complete newbie, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: e.g., `Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{
   {
    ContourPlot[Cos[a x] + Cos[y]
     , {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}
     ]
    , Plot[Cos[a x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
    }
   }]
 , {{a, 1}, 0.4, 2}
 ]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you write down an answer, I will be glad to accept.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I was suggesting the use of `GraphicsGrid` only. You can find plenty of examples of it on this site as well as in the docs. In addition, please check out `GraphicsColumn` and `GraphicsRow`. If you ask something more challenging I will participate in the Q/A if I can. Take care.