# Color consistency in Plot3D with 2D projection

Tags: plotting

This code adapted from [Placing a ContourPlot under a Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d) works pretty well.

```
u[x_, y_] := x^.5 y^.5
contour = 
 ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  Axes -> False, Contours -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, ColorFunction -> "Aquamarine"]
potential1 = 
 Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], LightBlue}}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {min, 2}}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
Show[potential1, 
 Graphics3D[contour[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

Here is the outcome:

[image]

I wonder how to reuse the color function on the contour plot to have identical colors.

Comment: `min` is missing.

Comment: As much fo me min = 0

Answer (score 6):

In `contour`, instead of `ColorFunction` place `ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], LightBlue}}`:

```
u[x_, y_] := x^.5 y^.5
contour = 
  ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Axes -> False, Contours -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], 
      LightBlue}}];
potential1 = 
  Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], LightBlue}}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {min, 2}}, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];
Show[potential1, 
 Graphics3D[contour[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0}], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]