# How to coordinate colors?

Tags: plotting

In this adaptation of an ancient post ( [Placing a ContourPlot under a Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/placing-a-contourplot-under-a-plot3d) ) I would like to know how to coordinate the colors of the surface on the color of the scheme `LightTerrain` or any other scheme. In other words, I wonder how to know which colors are used in a scheme.

```
 f = E^-(x^2 + y^2);

 min = 0;
 max = 1;
  f1 = Plot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
  ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], LightBlue}}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False];
  slice = SliceContourPlot3D[f, 
  z == min - 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, min - 2, min + 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {min, max}, Contours -> 15, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"];
 Show[f1, slice, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a look:

`AssociationMap[Blend["LightTerrain", #1] &, Range[0, 1, .05]]`

This is the simplest way to get the actual colors and here's why:

`ColorData` returns a `ColorDataFunction` which is really a special `InterpolatingFunction`-esque object.

In this case we get:

```
In[622]:= ColorData["LightTerrain"] // InputForm

Out[622]//InputForm=
ColorDataFunction["LightTerrain", "Gradients", {0, 1}, Blend["LightTerrain", #1] & ]
```

Then look at `ColorDataFunction // SubValues` to see what this does and it's really only `Blend["LightTerrain", #1] &` that's important here.

But the gradients defining `"LightTerrain"` in blend aren't obviously scrapeable. They're probably possible to find, but it's likely not worth it when you can just use the function.

Answer (score 3):

***"I wonder how to know which colors are used in a scheme"***

The blending colors for gradient color schemes can be obtained using the function `` DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument ``. For example:

```
DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["LightTerrain"]
```

[image]

For continuous gradient schemes (all except `"BrightBands"` and `"DarkBands"`) blending argument is just a list of colors. For a randomly selected 12 of continuous gradient schemes, the color lists are:

```
Grid[{#, Grid[{{"blend arguments: ", Row @ DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument @ #}, 
 {"image: ",  ColorData[#, "Image"]}}, Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, Center}]} & /@ 
  RandomSample[Delete[ColorData["Gradients"], {{10}, {16}}], 12], 
 Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, Center}]
```

[image]

For the two discontinuous schemes:

```
Grid[{#, Grid[{{"blend arguments: ", Row @ DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument @ #}, 
  {"image: ", ColorData[#, "Image"]}}, Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, Center}]} & /@ 
  ColorData["Gradients"][[{10, 16}]], 
 Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {{Left, Left}, Center}]
```

[image]