# Putting a 2D plot into a 3D plot

Tags: visualization

I'm trying to put a 2D plot (`ContourPlot`) into a 3D plot.

I started by adapting my [recipe](http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2010/12/making-anti-aliased-diagrams.html) from 8 years ago but I'm finding it to be quite user unfriendly/hard to use. For one, it's using `Rasterize` so additional tweaking is needed to get rid of blurriness. I'm wondering if I'm missing some features added in the last 8 years that would make this task easier to accomplish.

More specifically, I'm trying to put a 2D region plot on the top face of the bounding box of the following 3D region plot

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Dashed, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1]]]
RegionPlot3D[
 z < Exp[-x^2 - y^2] && x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 
  1}]
```

[image]

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14875/9490

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rp3d = RegionPlot3D[z < Exp[-x^2 - y^2] && x^2 + y^2 > 1, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5];

scp3d = SliceContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2, {"ZStackedPlanes",{1}}, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, Contours -> {1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Blue], BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Dashed,Blue], 
  ContourShading -> {Directive[Opacity[.3], Blue], Opacity[0]}];

Show[rp3d, scp3d]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, looks like `SliceContourPlot3D` is this new feature added in last 8 years :)

Comment: @Yaroslav, it is less than 3 years old:) Thank you for the accept.