# Plotting a 2D plot along the maxima of a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

so i have a function $f(x,y)$ (sorry i cannot provide the whole function, it is long transfer matrix function) which i have plotted onto a 3D plot to identify the max values of the function. In addition the variables $x$ and $y$ are constrained $0<x<0.6$ and $0<y<7$

[image]

i am looking for a way to plot the $f(x,y)_{MAX}$ (the red region) as a 2D plot $x$ Vs $y$. And hopefully combine it with the 3D plot.

I have already tried to use NMaximize and MaxValue functions but have failed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but within Plot3D you could set MeshFunctions -> {#3&} to draw contours of constant z. This would help visualize better than just color. For the specific parametric curve of the maximum you could use Show[{Plot3D[<your plot here>] , ParametricPlot3D[<your maxima function here>]}].

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't know about the ParametricPlot3D. Now I just need to find away to get the maxima function.

Comment: Realted [14863](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14863/10397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Surface

```
pl1 = Plot3D[
  Exp[-2 (y - Sin[x])^2]
  , {x, 0, 2 π}
  , {y, -2, 2}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , MaxRecursion -> 8
  , PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6]
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### The maximum

```
pl2 = ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, Sin[x], 1}
  , {x, 0, 2 π}
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### The bottom

```
pl3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Combined

```
Show[
 pl1,
 pl2,
 Graphics3D[
  pl3[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Comment: could you tell me how you obtained the maximum functions for the ParametricPlot3D ($f_x$, $f_y$, $f_z$)?

Comment: @JonathanWeerakkody In this case I constructed the 3D function to have that maximum. I would have calculated your case, but you didn't provide the code for the equation, and the question focuses in plotting.

Comment: is there a generalized way to find this maximum function. The equation i am using is very long and tedious and it has many variable paramenters hard to represent here

Comment: @JonathanWeerakkody Then probably it could be done numerically for a limited number of points and then plot the `InterpolatingFunction`. The generalized way is to find where the first derivative is zero and the second derivative negative, but complicated functions and domains may need special considerations.

Comment: thank you, i am actually trying that now. Is there anyway to get multiple points for the maximae using the Nmaximise option

Comment: @JonathanWeerakkody Try yourself by looking at the examples in the documentation and searching this site. If that is not enough then ask another question.