# How to combine a 3D plot and a 2D density plot?

Tags: plotting

I am new to mathematica and I know there are questions related to this topic but I could not find mine. My supervisor has asked me to shadowplot my Wigner functions which he showed me is like the following image:

[image]

From what I see, this image is a combination of a 3D plot and a 2D density plot of the Wigner function. This is an image from MATLAB but I want to plot my function using Mathematica as I have never used MATLAB before. I have tried plotting it like this:

```
a = -(E^-Abs[(0.` + 1.6487212707001282` I) p + 
      0.6065306597126334` q]^2/\[Pi]) + 
  0.6366197723675815` E^-Abs[(0.` + 1.6487212707001282` I) p + 
      0.6065306597126334` q]^2 Abs[(0.` + 1.6487212707001282` I) p + 
     0.6065306597126334` q]^2;

p1 = Plot3D[a, {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Small, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

p2 = DensityPlot[a, {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Small];

p3 = Plot3D[0, {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Texture[p2], 
  Mesh -> None]

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}];
```

But it gives me the following image:
[image]

How do I get my desired plot?

Moreover, how to do the same for the following complex expression because in this case using MinValue command doesn't work?

```
'''a1 = (2 E^(-2 Abs[-(1/Sqrt[2]) + I p + q]^2) (7 - 20 I Sqrt[2] p - 
 24 p^2 - 20 Sqrt[2] q + 48 I p q + 24 q^2 + 
 8 (-3 + 8 p^2 + 8 I p (Sqrt[2] - 2 q) + 8 Sqrt[2] q - 
    8 q^2) Conjugate[p]^2 + 
 4 (-5 Sqrt[2] + 16 Sqrt[2] p^2 + 28 q - 16 Sqrt[2] q^2 - 
    4 I p (-7 + 8 Sqrt[2] q)) Conjugate[q] + 
 8 (3 - 8 p^2 - 8 I p (Sqrt[2] - 2 q) - 8 Sqrt[2] q + 
    8 q^2) Conjugate[q]^2 + 
 4 Conjugate[
   p] (-16 I Sqrt[2] p^2 - 4 p (-7 + 8 Sqrt[2] q) + 
    I (5 Sqrt[2] - 28 q + 16 Sqrt[2] q^2) - 
    4 (-8 I p^2 + 8 p (Sqrt[2] - 2 q) + 
       I (3 - 8 Sqrt[2] q + 8 q^2)) Conjugate[
      q])))/(3 \[Pi] (Sqrt[2] - 4 I p - 4 q) (Sqrt[2] + 
 4 I Conjugate[p] - 4 Conjugate[q]))'''
```

Comment: A similar question is asked here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14863/4346

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html).

With `a` and `p1` in OP then find minimum to position slice.

```
min = MinValue[a, {p, q}]
```

> ```
> -0.31831
> ```

```
p3 = SliceDensityPlot3D[a, {"ZStackedPlanes", {min - .1}}
  , {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, {z, min - .1, min - .2}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

Show[p1, p3]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  It gave me exactly what I wanted. Now I know its too dumb to ask but did you auto-rotate this using mathematica?

Comment: @Anaya You just click and drag the plot in Mathematica to rotate it.

Comment: No I meant how to make it rotate like an animation. I want to add my plots to my presentation and if they are auto-rotating like the one above,  it would be more clear to my audience

Comment: @Anaya looks to me like he simply used some screen recorder. You can see the mouse cursor in the image. No idea which he used. but googling "screen recorder gif" gives several possibilities

Comment: @Anaya I used ShareX. I think it's open-source.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.

Comment: @Edmund I am trying to combine a 3D plot and a 2D density plot this time for a different expression which is complex. So I am unable to find its minimum value using the MinValue command.

Comment: @Edmund I have edited the question to insert the expression because its too long to be posted here in the comments. Kindly help. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
a = -(E^-Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
           0.6065306597126334 q]^2/\[Pi]) + 
   0.6366197723675815 E^-Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
         0.6065306597126334 q]^2 Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
       0.6065306597126334 q]^2;

p1 = Plot3D[a, {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> All];
p2 = Plot3D[a, {q, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   Lighting -> {DirectionalLight[White, {{1, 1, -5}, {1, 1, 0}}], 
     DirectionalLight[White, {{1, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 0}}]}];
Show[p2 /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y, -.5}, p1]
```

[image]

Comment: `SliceDensityPlot3D` also work.

Comment: For some reason my laptop just freezed running this.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = -(E^-Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
           0.6065306597126334 q]^2/\[Pi]) + 
   0.6366197723675815 E^-Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
         0.6065306597126334 q]^2 Abs[(0. + 1.6487212707001282 I) p + 
       0.6065306597126334 q]^2;

p1 = Plot3D[a, {p, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  , AxesLabel -> Automatic
  , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  , ImageSize -> Medium
  , AxesLabel -> {"p", "q", "W"}
  , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, Automatic}
  ]

p2 = SliceContourPlot3D[a
  , {z == -2}
  , {p, -2, 2}
  , {q, -2, 2}
  , {z, -4, 0}
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  , ContourStyle -> None
  , AxesLabel -> {"p", "q", "W"}
  , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, Automatic}
  ]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]