# Insert a 2D graph in a 3D graph

Tags: graphics

I have this question:
      Suppose I have some two dimsensional graphic element, say "flower" (i.e. a picture of a flower) in a *Mathematica* notebook.  I want to insert this figure, say at a specific point such as `(1,1,2)` in a 3-dimensional plot such as given by

```
Plot3D[x^2+y^2,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

I tried `Epilog` command with inset within the above Plot3D command, but was not succesful.  For example, I tried:

```
Plot3D[x^2+y^2,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},Epilog->{  Inset[flower,{1,1,2}]  } ].
```

The problem is possibly that `Inset` command only allows 2D coordinates.

Can someone please help me to achieve this task?
Thank you for any help in advance

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: A 2D plot is like a plane, don't you need to specify more info about it, other than it goes through a specific point ?

Answer (score 5):

Just to make sure I understand what you want first. Do you want like this:

[image]

With the help of this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7772/more-on-combining-2d-and-3d-plots) here is an example of the above. This allows you to change the z coordinate of the 2D image into the 3D image. You can do the same for the other coordinates if needed.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{p2g},
  p2g = Graphics3D[
    {
     EdgeForm[],
     Texture[p2],
     Polygon[{{-1, -1, z}, {1, -1, z}, {1, 1, z}, {-1, 1, z}},
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
      ]
     },

    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .1},
    Axes -> True
    ];
  Show[p1, p2g, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-10, 15}}]
  ],

 {{z, 15, "z="}, -3, 15, .1, ImageSize -> Small, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 SynchronousUpdating -> True,
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 Alignment -> Center,
 ImageMargins -> 0,
 FrameMargins -> 1,

 Initialization :> {
   p1 = Plot3D[x^3 + y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> 5, 
     ImageSize -> 300];
   p2 = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]