# How to draw a 2D curve as epilog on a 3D surface plot?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to draw

```
Plot[Re@Sin[x+I*2], {x, -10, 10}]
```

as an epilog on

```
Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

and position it at `y=2`.

What's intuitive to me doesn't work:

```
epilogData = Table[{x, 2, Re@Sin[x + 2*I]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}];

Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[epilogData]}]
```

Using

```
epilogData2D = Table[{x, Re@Sin[x + 2*I]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}];
```

will draws something, but not what i want (What's that anyway?).

I've also played with `Inset` and got no luck so far.

Comment: The function [Make3d](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3667/134) can be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe it helps to use `Mesh`:

```
Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, None}}, {{2, {Red, Thick}}}}]
```

[image: Plot3D with mesh]

With a varying `y`:

```
frames = Table[
  Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, None}}, {{i, {Red, Thick}}}}], {i, -10, 10, .5}];
Export["animation.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: How to make the animation?

Comment: @MonkeyKing See update.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
With[{y0 = 2}, 
     Show[Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
          Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], 
                      First[Plot[Re@Sin[x + I y0], {x, -10, 10}]] /.
                      v : {__?NumericQ} :> Insert[v, y0, 2]}]]]
```

[image: surface with marked line]

The use of `Mesh`, as in VLC's answer, is much easier, tho.

Answer (score 1):

`Mesh` as in VLC's answer is my favorite approach. Nevertheless, you can also use `Exclusions` and `ExclusionsStyle`:

```
Plot3D[Re@Sin[x + I*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
 Exclusions -> {Automatic, y == 2}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick]]
```

[image]