# Plot 2D B-spline curve on 3D B-spline surface

Tags: plotting, splines

I've been working on this for days. I am trying to plot the B-spline 2D curve (figure '8') on the 3D surface. How can I do that? Can anyone help me with this?

Here, I provide code that I use to generate the curve and the surface.

```
(* pick a data set *)
dataset = 3;

If[dataset == 3, (
   n = 3;  (* degree *)
   ll = 12;  (* domain intervals *)
   numd = n + ll - 1;
   dd = Table[{Cos[x/2] // N, 2 Sin[x] // N}, {x, 0, numd}])];

cpts1 = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{1, -1}]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];

oneside = {{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, -1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 3,0}},{{2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 3, 0}},                           {{3, 0, -1}, {3, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 0}, {3,3, -1}}};
b = Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[oneside]]
bT = Transpose[b];
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Black, Map[Point, oneside], Black,
Line[oneside], Line[Transpose[oneside]]}], b]

(*cpts2=Table[{i,j,RandomReal[{-1,1}]},{i,-1,1,2/5},{j,-1,1,2/5}];
ParametricPlot3D[BSplineFunction[cpts2][u,v],{u,0,1},{v,0,1},\
RegionFunction\[Rule](#1^2+#2^2\[LessEqual]1&)]*)



(* uniform knots *)
knot = Join[Table[0, {i, 0, n}], Table[i/ll, {i, 1, ll - 1}], 
Table[1, {i, 0, n}]] // N;
numk = Length[knot];

(* Extract the juntion points *)
(* Evaluate at the domain knots *)
jknots = Table[knot[[i]], {i, n + 1, numk - n, 1}];
jpts = Table[curve[knot[[i]]], {i, n + 1, numk - n, 1}];


(* curve evaluation *)
curve[t_] := Sum[BSplineBasis[{n, knot}, i, t]*dd[[i + 1]], {i, 0, numd}];

(* Plot *)
cplot = ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, knot[[n + 1]], knot[[numk - n]]},
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}];
points = Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[dd], 
PointSize[0.02], Point[dd[[1]]]}];
ddplot = ListLinePlot[dd];
jptsplot = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[jpts]}];
Show[{ddplot, cplot, points, jptsplot}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give the code you used to create both images? This will make it much easier for people to help

Comment: yeah sure no problem

Comment: Related: [(13735)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13735/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use texture:

```
texture = 
  Rasterize[
   Show[{ddplot, cplot, points, jptsplot}, Axes -> False, 
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}], "Image"];

f = BSplineFunction[oneside];

Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Black, Map[Point, oneside], Black,
    Line[oneside], Line[Transpose[oneside]]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[Rasterize[t]], Mesh -> None]]
```

[image]

or embedding 2d to 3d:

```
f8 = Show[{ddplot, cplot, points, jptsplot}];

f83d = (f8[[1]] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
     f[Rescale[x, {-1, 1}], Rescale[y, {-2, 2}, {0.25, .75}]]);

Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Black, Map[Point, oneside], Black,
    Line[oneside], Line[Transpose[oneside]]}], 
 Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[oneside], f83d}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much.