# 3D plot over an implicit region gives no answer

Tags: plotting, implicit

I have a function(X,Y) which I would like to plot over an implicit region.

```
ff[x_, y_] := 
 1.2975379589629985 - 0.0012761239122278919 *x + 
  0.000041783647037795416 *x^2 + 0.007921675950764907*y + 
  0.0000118850192022573*x*y - 0.0001707743989388566*y^2
```

The function looks something like this:

```
Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}]
```

[image: plot result]

The implicit region I want to use comes from the following set of equations and inequalities:

```
dd = ImplicitRegion[
  1.2975379589629985 - 0.0012761239122278919*x + 
     0.000041783647037795416*x^2 + 0.007921675950764907*y + 
     0.0000118850192022573*x*y - 0.0001707743989388566*y^2 == 
    1.3800 && 
   161.62615411060966 + 0.3806830725981278* x + 
     0.013569502726920852*x^2 + 12.429037516501275*y + 
     0.09556852733876661*x*y - 0.45752045618958564*y^2 > 220, {{x, 
    0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}}]
```

RegionPlot confirms that the implicit region is there:

```
RegionPlot[dd]
```

[image: Regionplot]

When I try to make the 3D plot over the implicit region the following way I get no answer from Mathematica 10.2:

```
Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ dd]
```

Is there a better way to plot such 3D plots or am I doing something wrong with my approach?

The final result I am aiming for is to combine the 3D plot from the original function and the 3D plot over the implicit region (curve) with Show to achieve something like this:
[image: wanted result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach for your newly stated goal.

```
p1 = Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}, Mesh -> None];

lines = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[dd], 1];

curve = Apply[{#, #2, ff[##]} &, lines, {-2}];

Show[p1, Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, curve}]]
```

[image]

Reference:

- [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html)
- [`MeshPrimitives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html)
- [Plot 2D bspline curve on 3D bspline surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131505/121)

If I find or think of a cleaner approach I shall post it, if someone has not already done so.

Extracting the line from `RegionPlot` seems to be faster than `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
line = Normal[RegionPlot @ dd][[1, 1, 1, -1]];

curve = Apply[{##, ff[##]} &, line, {-2}];
```

[`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) is needed to convert the [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) into a standard [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) expression with (x,y) coordinates rather than point indexes.  [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) extraction may be brittle as the specific form may change between versions (I am using 10.1) but a look at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) of the expression should help one find the [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) quickly enough.

---

#### Original answer

Your region has no [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html):

```
Area[dd]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Borrowing an example from the [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) documentation you can plot over this:

```
ir1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];

Area[ir1]

Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir1]
```

> ```
> π
> ```

[image]

But not this:

```
ir2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}];

Area[ir2]

Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir2]
```

> ```
> 0
>
> Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir2]
> ```

Comment: I have noticed something similar when I was playing with the examples in the online documentation - I could make plots when the implicitregion was any area, but couldnt do it with my implicitregion being a curve. 
Can you propose another way to do 3D plots over implicit curves?

Comment: @user350 I am having trouble visualizing what the output should be.  Consider what happens when you give this region a small area using an inequality: `ddx = ImplicitRegion[
  1.3799 < (1.2975379589629985 - 0.0012761239122278919*x + 
      0.000041783647037795416*x^2 + 0.007921675950764907*y + 
      0.0000118850192022573*x*y - 0.0001707743989388566*y^2) < 1.3801 && 
   161.62615411060966 + 0.3806830725981278*x + 0.013569502726920852*x^2 + 
     12.429037516501275*y + 0.09556852733876661*x*y - 0.45752045618958564*y^2 > 
    220, {{x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}}]`

Comment: Then plotting with `Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ddx]` gives a plot not much different in practicality from `RegionPlot[ddx]` itself.  If the region has *less* area what would be plotted other than the curve itself?

Comment: The reason is simply that I wanted to see the curve ploted in 3D so that I could later combine it with the original 3D plot with the Show function. I will edit the original question to show an example of what I wanted to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 1):

An other approach with ParametricPlot.

```
ff[x_, y_] = 
    1.2975379589629985 - 0.0012761239122278919*x + 
    0.000041783647037795416*x^2 + 0.007921675950764907*y + 
    0.0000118850192022573*x*y - 0.0001707743989388566*y^2;

dd = 1.2975379589629985 - 0.0012761239122278919*x + 
 0.000041783647037795416*x^2 + 0.007921675950764907*y + 
 0.0000118850192022573*x*y - 0.0001707743989388566*y^2 == 1.3800 &&
161.62615411060966 + 0.3806830725981278*x + 
 0.013569502726920852*x^2 + 12.429037516501275*y + 
 0.09556852733876661*x*y - 0.45752045618958564*y^2 > 220;

sol = Solve[dd, y];

p1 = Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
            Mesh -> None];

p2 = ParametricPlot3D[
        Evaluate[Thread[{x, yy = y /. sol, ff[x, yy]}]], {x, 0, 30}, 
        BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 30}, {1.3, 1.4}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}]

(*   Thread is only necessary for more than one conditional solutions   *)
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]