# Projecting image or contour plot on xy-plane of Histogram3D?

Tags: graphics3d

I've generated a simple 3D histogram, where the x-y coordinates corresponding to the "location" of an event defined on a simple 160x160 grid, and the z-axis height is simply the count of events that occur at each x-y location.

For this particular graph, I have an png image (think of it as a map) on which the 160x160 grid is defined. I'd like to use this image as the x-y floor of my Histogram3D. I'd also like to use a ListContourPlot as the x-y floor, in a companion image.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3667/134).

Answer (score 5):

Basically you can use `Show` to combine your `Histogram3D` object with a `Graphics3D` object. I use a `Polygon` with a `Texture` on it to hold the image. To make the image more visible you can set the opacity level of the `Histogram3D`:

```
Show[Histogram3D[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}], 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[0.4]], 
  Graphics3D[{Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]],
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]]
```

The above code gives the following representation:

[image]

The only thing you have to adjust for your particular case is to set the position of the polygon according to your data. Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using `Texture`:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100, 2}];

{g, {binCounts}} =  Reap[Histogram3D[data, {-2, 2, 0.25}, 
  Function[{xbins, ybins, counts}, Sow[counts]]]];

img1 = Image[MatrixPlot[First@binCounts, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
 DataReversed -> True,ImageSize -> 400]];

img2 = ExampleData@{"TestImage", "Peppers"};

hst3D = Histogram3D[data, {-2, 2, 0.25},  Function[{xbins, ybins, counts}, counts], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,(* Background -> Black,*)
 ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.3], ChartStyle -> Green,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0,  ImageSize -> 400]; 

Grid[{{hst3D, img1}, 
  Graphics3D[{hst3D[[1]], Texture[#], Opacity[.6], EdgeForm[], 
  Polygon[{Scaled@{0, 0, 0}, Scaled@{0, 1, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{1, 0, 0}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
  hst3D[[2]]] & /@{img1, img2}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]