# Replace expression, but only "outside" of a function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, replacement

I have a horrid expression, which is basically a sum of exponents with coefficients. Here's a taste:

[image]

What I want to do is to replace `ks` with another expression, but to do so only when `ks` appears outside an exponent. Alternatively, I want to preform this replacement, but keep the arguments of all exponents unchanged.

For example I want

```
SpecialReplace[(ks-foo*bar) Exp[ks^foo-bar],ks->Y]
```

to yield

```
(Y-foo*bar) Exp[ks^foo-bar]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Related: [(33025)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33025/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use two rules in the replacement with a dummy rule to replace exponents with themselves.

Along the lines of.

```
(ks-foo*bar) Exp[ks^foo-bar] /. {x:Exp[___]->x, ks->Y}
```

So anything that is an exponent is 'caught' by the first rule and the kx replacement rule doesn't get a look in.

Comment: Thanks. But lists of replacement rules are executed consecutively, so this will not work.

Comment: You're right it doesn't work, I have corrected it.  Not because the rules execute in sequence but because my first rule was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. Let this:

```
expr = (ks - foo1*bar1) Exp[ks^foo1 - bar1] + (ks - foo2*bar2) Exp[
 ks*foo2 - bar2];
```

This

```
pos = Position[expr, Exp[__]];
```

returns the position of exponents in it. Then this:

```
 expr2 = MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, ks -> kg] &, expr, pos] /. ks -> Y /. 
  kg -> ks

(*   E^(-bar1 + ks^foo1) (-bar1 foo1 + Y) + 
 E^(-bar2 + foo2 ks) (-bar2 foo2 + Y)       *)
```

makes the job.

Have fun!