# Substituting variables in only certain environments?

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

I was integrating a function and got something essentially like

```
E^(mu beta) * (1/beta)
```

There `beta` is defined as `1/(kT)`. I want to display the entire expression as

```
E^(mu beta) * (k T)
```

Is there a non-manual way to do that?

Comment: `Replace[E^(mu beta)*(1/beta), beta -> 1/(k T), 2]`?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71691/replace-expression-but-only-outside-of-a-function, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25538/substitution-rules-excluding-subscripted-variables

Comment: Thanks! It is the duplicate of the first question you linked, although not the second. Is there a way to let this question display that correct existing question so that I could mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One useful trick is to precede the rule with an identity rule matching the part that you don't want to change.  For example

```
E^(mu beta)*(1/beta) /. {u : mu beta -> u, beta -> 1/(k T)}
(* E^(beta mu) k T *)
```

This is obviously more useful in dealing with larger expressions