# Replace expressions outside certain functions

Tags: replacement

I'm trying to replace variables outside of certain functions. More precisely, in the standard ones like `Sin` substitution should work while in undefined `BC` and `u` (and all their derivatives) should not, and it always should work outside of any functions.
I checked [71691](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71691) and [33025](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33025) but found no suitable advice.

From this:

```
-x1 BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] Sin[x2]^2 u[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] + D[BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2],x1,x1]
```

With a substitution like `{x1->x1[t1,t2], x2->x2[t1,t2]}` I would like to get this:

```
-x1[t1,t2] BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] Sin[x2[t1,t2]]^2 u[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] + D[BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2],x1,x1]
```

Derivative is of course written with upper indices in the code. I'm trying (according to the previous answers) this:

```
EQ = -x1 BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] Sin[x2]^2 u[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2] + D[BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2],x1,x1];
EQPOS = Join[Position[EQ, BC[__]], Position[EQ, u[__]]];
EQPOSED = MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, {x1 -> EX1, x2 -> EX2, x3 -> EX3}] &, EQ, EQPOS] /. {x1 -> x1[t1, t2], x2 -> x2[t1, t2], x3 -> x3[t1, t2]} /. {EX1 -> x1, EX2 -> x2, EX3 -> x3}
```

As you can see this method fails to work with derivatives.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a pattern that can catch derivatives: `Join[Position[EQ, BC[__] | Derivative[__][BC][__]], Position[EQ, u[__] | Derivative[__][u][__]]]`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the execution order in a rule replacement list: once a part of an expression has been matched and replaced, it then remains untouched by subsequent replacement rules. With this trick we can make sure that `BC` and `u` are replaced with themselves first (so nothing happens to them and their arguments), and everything else is replaced according to the rules you give after that:

```
EQ = -x1*BC[x1,x2,x3,t1,t2]*Sin[x2]^2*u[x1,x2,x3,t1,t2] + D[BC[x1,x2,x3,t1,t2],x1,x1];

EQ /. {z : Through[(Identity | Derivative[__])[BC | u]][__] -> z, 
       x1 -> x1[t1, t2], x2 -> x2[t1, t2]}
```

> -BC[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2]*Sin[x2[t1, t2]]^2*u[x1, x2, x3, t1, t2]*x1[t1, t2] + Derivative[2, 0, 0, 0, 0][BC][x1, x2, x3, t1, t2]

[See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194128) for how to construct the above `z` pattern that matches `BC[__]`, `u[__]`, as well as all of their derivatives.