# Construct a pattern with an optional head

Tags: pattern-matching

How can I construct a pattern that matches both `f` and `h[f]` without using the symbol `f` more than once in the pattern definition? That is, how can I define a pattern `pattern` that allows for an optional head, and returns `{True, True}` when used in

```
MatchQ[pattern] /@ {f, h[f]}
```

I don't want to use the alternative pattern `pattern = f | h[f]`.

I've tried

```
pattern = (Identity | h)[f];
MatchQ[pattern] /@ {f, h[f]}
(* {False, True} *)
```

which matches `h[f]` but not `f`; it would only match an unevaluated `Identity[f]`. Is there a way to evaluate the pattern before application so that `Identity[f]` becomes `f` and matches?

See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194103).

Comment: Why is it so crucial to only use `f` once in the pattern? What's wrong with something like `f[_] | Derivative[__][f][_]`? You can always use something like `With[{symbol = f}, ...]` if you want to write `f` only once.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I'm trying to learn more about pattern matching and feel like I'm missing a puzzle piece here. Your workarounds are of course valid but they aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe someone knows a trick I don't know, but I don't think you can do this any more elegantly than with `Alternatives`. I don't know of any way to match an optional head-of-a-head like you're trying to do here. `Optional` or `BlankNullSequence` don't work here at least.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit what about using some kind of `Default`? I don't know how to use it here though as I'm trying to default the head, not an argument as usual.

Comment: Simplified the question now: removed the irrelevant discussion of `Derivative`, so the focus is on the optional head issue.

Comment: So could you please give a list of expressions and indicate which should be matched and which others should not?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I've added a minimal list that needs to be matched.

Comment: One might be able to do what OP want by leveraging with `OneIdentity`.

Comment: @Silvia this could be the ticket! I didn't realize what this attribute was for until you commented. Why don't you amplify this comment into an answer?

Comment: I seems to not being able to come up a pattern simple while not matching almost everything.

Comment: @Silvia I will try too when I finally get to a computer. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Silvia the issue seems to be this point in the documentation ("possible issues") of `OneIdentity`: "In order for `f[a]` to match `a`, you must use a pattern that includes `Optional`." As you say, the resulting pattern then matches almost anything.

Answer (score 7):

I find that `Through` will make it work:

```
pattern = Through[(Identity | h)[f]];
MatchQ[pattern] /@ {f, h[f]}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

But it works just because in fact `Through` transforms `(Identity | h)[f]` into `f | h[f]`.

Comment: That's a start, thanks. I guess I'd like to transform/execute the pattern at match-time, not at define-time; but the idea is there in your solution.

Comment: @Roman With pleasure. If there are more ‘elegant’ approaches, please let me know.

Comment: I've adopted your solution for the linked problem at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194103

Comment: I know it's not what you are looking for, but `pattern := Through[(Identity | h)[f]]` doesn't transform at definition time.

Comment: That's right @mikado, but as soon as I use the pattern in a non-delayed setting it gets evaluated right away. For example, define `Q[x : Through[(Identity | h)[f]]] = x` and then check `?Q`: you see that the definition of `Q` contains the evaluated alternative pattern `f|h[f]`.

Comment: @Roman Not sure if this is exactly the same thing or not: `pattern = (h[#] | #) &[f, Identity]`

Comment: @MelaGo this is exactly the same alternative pattern, as it evaluates immediately to `pattern = h[f] | f` when the first argument `f` is inserted into the anonymous function. The second argument `Identity` in your list of arguments is unused; what was your idea for putting it there?

Comment: @Roman Hmm good point, I don't know what I was thinking. How about `pattern = h_: Null[f]`?

Comment: @MelaGo this matches `f` as well as `h[f]`! For the wrong reasons though, as (1) it matches `g[f]` as well (it's not specific to `h` as a head), and (2) `Optional::optloose` is thrown and the default value `Null` is not used at all (you can replace it by anything else). After all, `MatchQ[f, Null[f]]` would have returned `False`.

Comment: @Roman You're right that's awful. OK this is my last try, I promise. You're not going to like it: `StringMatchQ[ToString[#], RegularExpression["(h\[)*f\]*"]]`

Comment: Thanks @MelaGo that's very creative! With the RegExp "(h\[)?f\]?" it works even better as this doesn't match `h[h[f]]` etc. Technically it's a valid solution, but you're right I don't like it in this context. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roman One more. `(MatchQ[Head[#], (h | Symbol)] && 
  MatchQ[Switch[Length[#], 0, #, 1, #[[1]]], f])`

Comment: @MelaGo that works as well but it's two patterns, not a single one. Thanks a lot for your input, I'll be thinking more about this and maybe something comes together from all of these partial solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Condition`.

```
MatchQ[a_ /; (Last@Level[a, {-1}] == f)] /@ {f, h[f]}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Or `PatternTest`

```
MatchQ[a_?(Not@*FreeQ[f])] /@ {f, h[f]}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: These conditional patterns all match too broadly: they'll match all of `{f, h[f], g[f], h[h[f]]}` etc. Is there a way of constraining them?