# How to replace all the derivatives of a particular function?

Tags: replacement

For a given expression, such as:

```
exp=p[x]+p'[x]+p''[x]...Derivative[n][p][x]
```

I want to replace all the derivatives of `p[x]` to a constant `1`. But the following rule:

```
rule=Derivative[_][p][x]:>1
```

works for the derivatives when `n>=1`, except `p[x]. That is:

```
p'[x]/.rule
(* output: 1 *)

p''[x]/.rule
(* output: 1 *)

p[x]/.rule
(* output: p[x] *)
```

I wonder what is the correct rule to replace all the `Derivative[n][p][x]` to `1`, including `p[x]`.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not elegant, but works: `rule={Derivative[_][p][x] :> 1, p[x] :> 1}`

Comment: @Oscillon there are almost 15 rules... so this solution will double the input work. Oh... we do need some solution to reduce our labour.

Comment: Try `rule = p[x] | Derivative[_][p][x] :> 1`.

Comment: If you need it to be more general (i.e. you need to set *every* derivative to 1), then you can use a variation of @Somos's suggestion: `rule = _[x] | Derivative[_][_][x] :> 1` or something there-abouts.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194099 ?

Comment: @march En.  It seems the method from Somo is viable. Only part of the function should be modified, not all the function. More precisely, I would have revised the arbitrary order derivatives of a particular function.

Answer (score 2):

Given such an expression:

```mathematica
exp = Sum[Derivative[i][p][x], {i, 0, 7}]
```

A nice way would be to replace it by a pure function:

```mathematica
exp /. {p :> (1 &)}
(* 1 *)
```

which replaces all derivatives *and* the original function.

Comment: I believe the desired output of replacing all the derivatives should be `8`, not `1`. Here's a cute way to use a pure function: `exp /. p -> (Exp[# - x] &)`. Works only if the argument to the derivatives of `p` is `x`.