# Replace x, but not x[a]

Tags: replacement

I want to replace all occurences of the symbol `x` with `x[a]`, as long as it is not in the form `x[a]`.

In other words, I am looking for `magicReplacementRule` in

```
x[a] + x /. magicReplacementRule
--> x[a] + x[a]
```

I tried

```
x[a] + x /. Except[x[a], x] -> x[a]
```

but the result was `x[a][a] + x[a]`.

Comment: `Replace[x[a] + x, x -> y, {1}]`?

Comment: ... also `x[a] + x /. {x -> y, z : _[_] :> z}`?

Comment: How about `x[a] + x /. {x[a] -> x[a], x -> x[a]}`

Comment: @ChipHurst: Yes, that of course works. I feel sufficiently foolish now. (I think I had tried `{x[a] -> x, x -> x[a]}`, which was nonsense.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` with the option `Heads -> False`.

```
Replace[x[a] + x, x -> y, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> False]
```

`{0, Infinity}` here is a [level specification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) which tells `Replace` to replace everywhere, just like `ReplaceAll`.  You can drop `Heads -> False` because it's the default setting for `Replace`, but I wanted to point out the option which controls this behaviour.

---

**Update:**   It appears that since version 10, `All` can be used as a substitute for the `{0, Infinity}` level specification:

```
Replace[x[a] + x, x -> y, All]
```

Comment: You can use `-1` instead of `Infinity` in lvl specs, especially if you're concerned about character count.

Comment: @rcollyer When I read this, I thought: wouldn't it be easier to just have a level specification `All` that stands for `{0, Infinity}`? It turns out it works, but I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: You might be right. I'll hunt for it, too.

Comment: @rcollyer Just tried in 8 and 9.  It seems this is new in v10.  Only tested it in `Level` and `Replace`.  Perhaps it doesn't yet work in all function that take level specifications.

Answer (score 2):

In the [depth-first preorder traversal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121) of `ReplaceAll` complete expressions are matched before heads therefore one can use a skip rule<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25538/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32899/121)</sup>.  Since you also want to replace `x` with `x[a]`, the pattern to be skipped, you can use a single rule with [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html):

```
{x[a], x} /. x[a] | x -> x[a]
```

> ```
> {x[a], x[a]}
> ```

( Since `Plus[x[a], x[a]]` evaluates to `2 x[a]` I used `List` in the example above. )

Comment: I often use `expr /. {pat -> pat, old -> new}` -- explicitly here `expr /. {x[a] -> x[a], x-> x[a]}` -- but `Alternatives` works here since `pat` and `new` are the same. +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you have an answer where this "skip rule" features prominently?  I'll add it to my superscript links above.

Comment: Sorry, nothing turns up.  I *think* I've used it on this site. Unfortunately, `Cases[SemanticImport["MSE", "CodeBlock"], {p_ -> p_, __}, Infinity]` does not do what I want. :)

Comment: @Michael While looking for another example I realized this question is a duplicate. :-/

Answer (score 1):

because the x you want to replace is in the last level of the expression you can use:

```
Replace[Sin[x] + x[a] + x, x -> y, {-1}]
    (*y + Sin[y] + x[a]*)
```