# How to define a Rule to match a Head except if it is a Part of another?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have an `expr` which has `List` at various levels and I want to display them nicely as a column inside a frame but my problem is that the search for `List` goes inside things like `DateObject` to ruin their structure.

```
Replace[
    expr,
    x_List/;!MatchQ[...[...x...],DateObject[x,__]]:>Framed[Column@x]
    All
]
```

So how should I define such a `Rule`?

---

Sample `expr`:

```
{1->a,2->b,3->c,4->{5->d,6->e,7->Today},8->Yesterday,9->{10->f,11->{12->Tomorrow,13->g}}}
```

---

Current output:

```
Framed[Column[{1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> Framed[Column[{5 -> d, 6 -> e, 7 -> DateObject[Framed[Column[{2020, 1, 28}]], "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic]}]], 
       8 -> DateObject[Framed[Column[{2020, 1, 27}]], "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic], 
       9 -> Framed[Column[{10 -> f, 11 -> Framed[Column[{12 -> DateObject[Framed[Column[{2020, 1, 29}]], "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic], 13 -> g}]]}]]}]]
```

Desired output:

```
Framed[Column[{1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> Framed[Column[{5 -> d, 6 -> e, 7 -> DateObject[{2020, 1, 28}, "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic]}]], 
       8 -> DateObject[{2020, 1, 27}, "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic], 
       9 -> Framed[Column[{10 -> f, 11 -> Framed[Column[{12 -> DateObject[{2020, 1, 29}, "Day", CalendarType -> "Gregorian", DateFormat -> Automatic], 13 -> g}]]}]]}]]
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample `expr`? It's hard to provide help if other people don't have anything they can evaluate.

Comment: @J.M. sample `expr` added.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what exactly you want the output to look like. Are you trying to extract every expression that has `List` as a `Head` and then put those in a column? Or are you trying to extract just the rules at level 1, or what? Can you give a (rough) example of your desired output?

Comment: @march There is no extraction, it is a replacement problem at any level. See the current vs desired output.

Comment: Related: [(25538)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25538/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is [`` Developer`ReplaceAllUnheld ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ReplaceAllUnheld.html).

```
expr = {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> {5 -> d, 6 -> e, 7 -> Today}, 8 -> Yesterday, 
   9 -> {10 -> f, 11 -> {12 -> Tomorrow, 13 -> g}}};

Block[{DateObject},
 Attributes[DateObject] = HoldAll; 
 Developer`ReplaceAllUnheld[expr, List -> Framed@*Column@*List]
]
```

[image]

Also see [What is the potential usage of ReplaceAllUnheld in Developer Utilities Package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132588/121)

Comment: Thank you all for the wonderful answers and I have upvoted all of them but after careful consideration, I am accepting this one since it is very easy to extend and I don't have to define additional rules.

In my application, I had to skip multiple `Head`s and just increasing `Block` variables and a line like `SetAttributes[{DateObject,Entity,Style,Missing},HoldAll];` seemed far convenient than defining separate rules.

Comment: @user13892 I am glad my answer was useful, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the fact that once an object is replaced, it doesn't get replaced by any further rules. So, just add a rule that replaces a `DateObject` with itself:

```
expr = {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> {5 -> d, 6 -> e, 7 -> Today}, 8 -> Yesterday, 9 -> {10 -> f, 11 -> {12 -> Tomorrow, 13 -> g}}}l
expr /. {a_DateObject :> a, List -> Framed@*Column@*List}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain the reason for changing `x_List:>Framed[Column@x]` to `List->Framed@*Column@*List` and why the former doesn't work in your trick?

Comment: Also, can you provide a solution that works with `Replace[#,{rules},All]&` rather than `ReplaceAll[#,{rules}]&`.

Comment: @user13892 you won't be able to get this to work well with `Replace[#, {rules}, All]&` since that traverses the expression tree from the lowest level upwards. You really do need `ReplaceAll`.  And `List->Framed@*Column@*List` is replacing the `Head` `List` with (in essence) the function `(Framed@Column@List[##]&)` which just means that you never need to bind `x`

Answer (score 5):

We can get the desired result using `Replace` in several ways:

**1.** We can temporarily change the behavior of `Framed` inside expressions with head `DateObject` (using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) and [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)):

```
Block[{Framed}, 
 Framed /: DateObject[Framed[a_], b___] := DateObject[First @ a, b]; 
 Replace[expr, a_List :> Framed[Column @ a], All]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Block[{Framed}, 
 Framed /: DateObject[Framed[Column[a_]], b___] := DateObject[a, b];
 Replace[expr, a_List :> Framed[Column@a], All]]
```

> same picture

**2.** Alternatively, we can use two replacement rules where the second rule  *undoes* the replacements inside `DateObject`s effected by the first rule:

```
Replace[expr, {a_List :> Framed[Column@a], d_DateObject :> (d /. Framed -> First)}, All]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Replace[expr, {List -> Framed@*Column@*List, 
  DateObject -> (DateObject[##] /. Framed -> First &)}, All, Heads -> True]
```

> same picture

Note the need to use the option `Heads -> True` in the second approach.