# How to control the layering of graphics displayed with Show

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, display

I am trying to combine two graphics objects using `Show`.

The first one is an isosurface:

```
data = Import["/PATH/furan-ks.sdat", "Table"];
ALEE = Nearest[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]];
cfALEE = ColorData["Rainbow"]@First@ALEE[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
isosurface=ListSurfacePlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> cfALEE, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 25, 
ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: isosurface]

The second one is a sequence of points:

```
 geom = Import["/PATH/furan.geom", "Table"];
 AngToAu = 1.88971616463;
 Function[x, x*AngToAu];
 geom = Map[%, geom, {2}];
 Show[Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.05], Point[geom]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: points]

I want the points to appear on the same plot as the surface and be plotted at the appropriate scale. A command I am using:

```
Show[isosurface, Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.05], Point[geom]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

The catch is that the points effectively appear inside the surface and are NOT visible. I need to somehow project them on the surface or make them visible through the surface.

How do I deal with this? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: attached the files
[isosurface](http://www77.zippyshare.com/v/94354937/file.html)
[geom](http://www77.zippyshare.com/v/1922790/file.html)

Comment: You could make `Tube`s out of it? I'm afraid that you should provide the code for the isosurface and the points so one can reproduce it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Opacity` directive for the code that generates `isosurface`?

Comment: you may use Overlay and SetAlphaChannel Overlay[{isosurface, 
  SetAlphaChannel[
   Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.05], Point[geom]}, 
    Boxed -> False], .5]}, All, 2]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/can-2d-and-3d-plots-be-combined-so-that-the-2d-plot-is-the-bottom-surface-of-the

Comment: added the code and the data

Comment: @molkee [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IQenF.png) would be it with `Tube` :)

Comment: @Öskå lol,I will play with it

Comment: @molkee What exactly would you wish? A see through solution? A `Tube` solution? One could also simply put the points on the surface.. :)

Comment: @Öskå can you paste your code for the `Tube` solution here?

Comment: @molkee In the mean time, if you are hurry: `{# - {4, 0, 0}, # + {4, 0, 0}} & /@ geom;
Show[Graphics3D[Tube[#, 0.1] & /@ %], isosurface]`

Comment: @molkee Or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UFgwN.png) can be easily done as well.

Comment: @Öskå thanks a lot! I need something to get done asap, you are right!

Comment: Well, if you want the see-through solution just add `PlotStyle -> Opacity@.5` to `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

Comment: Use spheres instead of points. They will poke through the surface.

Comment: @Öskå nope;) thanks for the help.

Comment: @molkee That's what I thought :) I'm glad to help but it's also good sometimes to get credits from it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would propose:

```
AngToAu = 1.88971616463;
geom = AngToAu*Import["~/Downloads/furan.geom", "Table"];
pts = Show[
   Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.05], Point[geom]}, Boxed -> False]];

data = Import["~/Downloads/furan-ks.sdat", "Table"];
ALEE = Nearest[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]] -> Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]];
cfALEE = ColorData["Rainbow"]@First@ALEE[{#1, #2, #3}] &;
data = data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
isosurface = 
  ListSurfacePlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 25, ImageSize -> 250, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
      And @@ (Norm[{y - #[[2]], z - #[[3]]}] >= .4 & /@ geom)], 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity@.5]
```

Producing your *shell* with holes as a projection of `geom` thanks to `RegionFunction`:

[image]

Then, you can either add your points:

```
Show[pts, isosurface]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or create `Tube`s out of them:

```
points = Cases[Normal[isosurface], Line[x__] :> x, \[Infinity]];
centers = Mean /@ (Select[#, First@# > 0 &] & /@ points /. {{} -> Sequence[]});
coorTube = {# - {First@#2, 0, 0}, # + {First@#2, 0, 0}} & @@@ 
  Thread@{SortBy[geom, Last], SortBy[centers, Last]};
Show[
  Graphics3D[{White, Opacity@.5, Tube[#, 0.4] & /@ coorTube}, Boxed -> False],
  pts, isosurface]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, rasterize the 3d and overlay a 2d graphic:

```
     Show[{Rasterize[ 
           Show[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Torus"}], ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1}] ,
                ImageSize -> {400, 400}], Graphics[Disk[125 {Sin[2 # Pi/6],
                     Cos[2 # Pi/6]} + {200, 200}, 20] & /@ Range[6]]}]
```

[image]