# Combine ListLinePlot and ListPlot3D using Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I want to plot something very similar to what is plotted by @Sjoerd C. de Vries in [Can 2D and 3D plots be combined so that the 2D plot is the bottom surface of the 3D plot boundary?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/can-2d-and-3d-plots-be-combined-so-that-the-2d-plot-is-the-bottom-surface-of-the)
I need to combine a ListPlot3D with ListLinePlot. I have manged to include ListLinePlot following his method but I was not able to include the ListPlot3D. Here a toy a simple example:

```
iz = -2;
aa = 1;
a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3/5}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -6/5}, {1, 1, 4/5}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}, PlotStyle -> Red]; surfacePlot = 
Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
  Polygon[{{-aa, -aa, iz}, {aa, -aa, iz}, {aa, aa, iz}, {-aa, aa, 
     iz}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 
      1}, {0, 1}}]}}], a}]
```

Please, understand that the ListPlot3D shown here is a toy example of the real one, which has curved complex structure, not simple plans. Therefore, I really need a solution in which I just include the ListPlot3D in the Graphics3D.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for. You can directly combine `Graphics3D` using `Show` command.

```
a = ListPlot3D[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, -6}, {5, 5, 4}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}];
surfacePlot = 
 Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
      Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
          1}}]}}], a}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now let us change a such it has a squre cross section : a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3/5}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, -6/5}, {1, 1, 4/5}}]; 1) Can you make them match in such a way that both occupy the entire section of the box.2) Can you make both figures keep their original colour... ?

Comment: Also push the ListLinePlot below so that they dont touch by doing ...Polygon[{{-1, -1, -4}, {1, -1, -4}, {1, 1, -4}, {-1, 1, -4}}...

Comment: @Mencia I still do not understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide more info?

Comment: @Mencia you can update them in the question.

Comment: I just edited the question, 1) now I want that the area of the section of the ListPlot3D (the projection to the z=0 plane)matches with the section of the LitLinePlot. 2) Also I would like both figures to keep the colours they have if you plot them independently.

Comment: @Mencia what do you mean by saying matches the section? `Show` command does not change color of the figure.

Comment: could we have a private chat discussion please?

Comment: Mr.Wizard♦ do you know how can I change the size and move around the ListPlot3D "a", inside the combined figure?