# Move figures inside function Show

Tags: graphics3d

I have a ListLinePlot and a ListPlot3D that I want to combine using Show. I do not know how to change the positions of the figures. Here a toy example:

```
a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0.25, 
 0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5, 1}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}];
Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
 Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
     1}}]}}], a}]
```

How can I center the figure "a" ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Is there a difference to your previous question?

Comment: @Yves Klett It is all related. Now is further issues related to the same problem I am attacking.

Comment: What do you mean by center? The figure "a" is defined by the points in your `ListPlot3D`. You can change your `Polygon` so the figure "a" will take all space in XY plane: `Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Axes -> True], a}]`

Comment: @BlacKow thank very much, that solves it. I have a further problem. I want the background of the ListLinePlot to be white. In order to do that I do Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Axes -> True, Lighting -> "Neutral"], a}] . But then, the figure "a" also becomes white. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you trying to achieve by using the 2D plot as a `Texture`. The following code gives me  white background:

```
a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0.25, 
     0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5, 1}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}];
Show[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True], a}]
```

[image]

`Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}` is another way to make your polygon white.

Although you should probably consider plotting your figure "b" in 3D instead of mapping it as a texture.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9, in my case the figure b also becomes white using  Lighting -> "Neutral"

Comment: Try to change `Lighting` in your  `ListPlot3D` too? E.g `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}` I don't have have V9, so I can't test it.

Comment: Ok, I will open a new question to solve this issue. Thank very much!

Comment: Consider telling us the final goal of your visualization. Community can come up with more elegant solutions rather than using `Texture`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard♦ suggested that I should use        Texture        , in a comment under PlatoManiac's answer in this post:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/can-2d-and-3d-plots-be-combined-so-that-the-2d-plot-is-the-bottom-surface-of-the

Comment: the final goal is to combine some 2D figures with a 3D figure.

Comment: do you know how could I increase the quality of the 2D figures? Something with Rasterize maybe ?

Comment: I solved the resolution problem @BlacKow